# compiling C issue "no such directory"

Tags: c, compilation

When trying to compile main.c:

$ gcc main.c -O main

gcc:error:no such file or directory exists

But when i get rid of the file name and let it output to a.out, it works fine.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, still getting used to the command line.

Comment: Remember that unix utilities generally have case sensitive options.

Answer (score 1):

You want `-o` (lowercase), not `-O`. `-O` specifies an optimization level, and then `gcc` thinks (since `-O` doesn't take an argument) you're just trying to compile a second file called `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Capital 'O' is for optimization options. Use lowercase 'o' instead:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main
```

Answer (score 0):

It's -o main not -O. (lower case)

gcc main.c -o main

Answer (score 0):

Use a lower-case o in the -o option.
-O is the option to enable the optimiser